# Disparity image publishing

Tags: stereo, stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am new to opencv. Need some help in publishing the disparity image in ROS.
i am getting left, right and disparity images from the custom stereo camera SDK. The disparity image that i am getting from SDK is mono8 format.
Now i want to publish the disparity image from the ROS so that "disparity_view" can display the disparity image.
It looks the disparity_view expects the images to be in TYPE_32FC1 format, but the disparity image that i have is mono8 format because of this it is not able to display disparity image.

Is there any sample program or tutorial which will guide to publish disparity image in TYPE_32FC1 format from mono8 format.

Warm Regards,
pramod

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9510/disparity-image-publishing/) by [prbhagwat](https://answers.ros.org/users/108/prbhagwat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2011-03-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Augusto Luis Ballardini](https://answers.ros.org/users/234/augusto-luis-ballardini/) on 2015-06-30**:
i'm going to add some lines of code, the question has an answer but with code is better ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

disparity_view expects disparities to have type `float`, so you'll need to convert your `uint8_t` disparity values. In your `DisparityImage` message, resize `image.data` to `width * size * sizeof(float)`, and get a float pointer to your data buffer: `float* ptr = reinterpret_cast<float*>(&image.data[0])`. Then copy the disparities over one by one. You may need to scale the `uint8_t` disparities down by some factor if the custom SDK does sub-pixel correspondence like OpenCV's block matcher. The `float` disparities are in pixels. Don't forget to set `image.encoding = sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_32FC1`.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I'm resuming this very old question
> since I'm trying to publish a
> disparityImage message, loading the
> values from a png file, but I'm stuck
> with this. Does anybody have a working
> example? Thank you. Augusto

ok I have some code to share

```
ros::Publisher publisher   = node.advertise<stereo_msgs::DisparityImage>("test",1,true);

// Allocate new disparity image message
stereo_msgs::DisparityImagePtr disp_msg = boost::make_shared<stereo_msgs::DisparityImage>();

cv::Mat cv_image;

full_filename_image = dir_image + boost::str(boost::format("%010d") % entries_played ) + ".png";
cv_image = cv::imread(full_filename_image, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

// you need to know only this params for a basic usage (0-64, st.img.proc default param here)
disp_msg->min_disparity = 0;
disp_msg->min_disparity = 63;

// should be safe
disp_msg->valid_window.x_offset = 0;
disp_msg->valid_window.y_offset = 0;
disp_msg->valid_window.width    = 0;
disp_msg->valid_window.height   = 0;
disp_msg->T                     = 0;
disp_msg->f                     = 0;
disp_msg->delta_d               = 0;
disp_msg->header.stamp          = ros::Time::now();
disp_msg->header.frame_id       = ros::this_node::getName(); 
disp_msg->header.seq            = progress.count(); //a counter, int type

sensor_msgs::Image& dimage = disp_msg->image;
dimage.width  = cv_image.size().width ;
dimage.height = cv_image.size().height ;
dimage.encoding = sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_32FC1;
dimage.step = dimage.width * sizeof(float);
dimage.data.resize(dimage.step * dimage.height);
cv::Mat_<float> dmat(dimage.height, dimage.width, reinterpret_cast<float*>(&dimage.data[0]), dimage.step);

cv_image.convertTo(dmat,dmat.type());

publisher.publish(disp_msg);
```

---

Originally posted by [Augusto Luis Ballardini](https://answers.ros.org/users/234/augusto-luis-ballardini/) with karma: 430 on 2015-06-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2